# how to set increment variable when add or remove elements dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set increment id whenever i add a new column.

this is how i am dynamically creating new element in a row.

```
<script>
    $(".imgAdd").click(function(){
      $(this).closest(".row").find('.imgAdd').before('<div class="col-sm-4 imgUp"><input id="gallery1" class="uploadFile tourbanner"><i class="fa fa-times del"></i></div>');
    });
    $(document).on("click", "i.del" , function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
</script>
```

this is html part where i am generating the div

```
    <div class="row" id="container">

<!--dynamically added column here -->

    <i class="fa fa-plus imgAdd"></i>
    </div>
```

what i need is, when i add new column, it should set increment variable +1, then it should output like.

```
<div class="row" id="container">
    
    <div class="col-sm-4 imgUp"><input id="gallery1" class="uploadFile tourbanner"><i class="fa fa-times del"></i></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 imgUp"><input id="gallery2" class="uploadFile tourbanner"><i class="fa fa-times del"></i></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 imgUp"><input id="gallery3" class="uploadFile tourbanner"><i class="fa fa-times del"></i></div>

<i class="fa fa-plus imgAdd"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable which will have `count value` and everytime `increment` it by 1 whenever new inputs are added and when a input get delete you can use `each` loop to reset the `ids` of the inputs.

**Demo Code** :

```js
var counter = 1;//declare count
$(".imgAdd").click(function(){
//add id=galery+counter
      $(this).closest(".row").find('.imgAdd').before('<div class="col-sm-4 imgUp"><input id="gallery'+counter+'" class="uploadFile tourbanner"><i class="fa fa-times del">DELETE</i></div>');
      counter++;//increment
    });
    $(document).on("click", "i.del" , function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
         counter--;//decremnt count
       reset();//reseting ids
    });
    
  
  function reset() {
    counter = 1;//start count from 1
    //loop 
    $(".tourbanner").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('id','gallery'+counter);//change ids
        counter++;//increment
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="container">
    
  
<i class="fa fa-plus imgAdd">ADD</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After you complete the change in the contents of #container, use a .each() function to reassign the ids:

```
  $i = 0;
  $("#container div").each(function() {
     $(this).prop("id","gallery"+ ++$i);
   });
```